# Basic AJAX request Javascript/PHP not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm attempting a basic AJAX call where I send the address 'www.google.com' to `urlpost.php` but the current code doesn't seem to be able to detect a response (nothing happens). I tried to look for the error but I don't know where I went wrong.

Thank you all in advance!

Disclaimer: This is an variation of an example from Robin Nixon's *Learning PHP, MySQL & Javascript*

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Ajax Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 align='center'>Loading a web page into a DIV</h1>
    <div id='info' align='center'>This Sentence will be replaced </div>
    <script>
        request = new ajaxRequest()
        request.open("POST", "urlpost.php", true) //also tried 'test/urlpost.php' (test is the folder of the file)
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
        request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")                

        request.send("url=www.google.com")

        request.onreadystatechange = ajaxCallback

        function ajaxCallback()
        {
            alert("Reponse received") //just letting me know I got a reponse
            if(this.readyState==4) //ready
            {
                if (this.status==200) //no idea
                    {
                        if (this.responseText != null)
                            {
                                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText
                            }
                        else alert("AJAX ERROR: NO DATA RECEIVED")
                    }
                    else alert("Ajax error: "+this.statusText);
            }
        }

        function ajaxRequest()
        {
            try //non IE browser
            {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e1)
            {
                try // IE6+?
                {
                    request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch(e2)
                {
                    try // IE5?
                    {
                        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")                   
                    }
                    catch(e3) //No Ajax support
                    {
                        request = false
                    }
                }
            }   
            return request
        }

    </script>
```

urlpost.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['url'])){
    echo file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['url']);
}

?>
```

Comment: To debug your example, you should try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or the embedded debugger if you use a webkit browser. You will see if the request is sent or not, and can put breakpoints.

Comment: Also, for an easier debug, use a simpler code in your urlpost.php file, like `<?php echo "Hello" ?>`. You will deal with the POST variable later.

Comment: IE5 support? ... I'm speechless!

Comment: put the script tag in the <head> ?

Comment: use the developer console to debug

Comment: your code is a bit oldfashioned by the way. It would be easier and better to use jQuery for this.

Comment: I posted a solution below, but OP isn't answering.

Comment: I'm learning from a book published in 2009 so I guess it might be a little outdated :) thanks for the feedback everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)`

`params.length` is undefined. You need to replace this by the length of the data you're sending

`request.send("url=www.google.com")` in your case that's 18 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery to rewrite it, much easier.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "urlpost.php",
            data: "url=www.google.com",

            success: function(msg){
                $('#replace').html(msg);

            }
        });
    return false;

});​
```